Matrix representation of direct sum of linear operators
Given two vector spaces $V,W$ over $K$, let $F\in L(V), T\in L(W). $
If $B,U$ are ordered basis for $V,W,$ respectively, show that the matrix $\left[F\right]_B\bigoplus \left[T\right]_U$ represents the operator $F\bigoplus T$.

The operator is given by $(v,w)\mapsto (F(v), T(w)).$
Let $B=\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ and $U=\{w_1,...,w_m\}$ be basis for $V, W$ respectively.
If I remember correctly, the direct sum of two matrices is a block diagonal matrix. This is, $[F]_B\bigoplus [T]_U=
\begin{pmatrix} [F]_B & 0\\
0 & [T]_U \end{pmatrix}.$
But I'm struggling to formally prove this direct sum of matrices represents the operator $F\bigoplus T$.

Verify that $B\cup U$ is a basis for $V\oplus W$, and then see how to express $F\oplus T$ on the vectors of $B\cup U$ in terms of $B\cup U$.
